# Java deadlock problem

Tags: java, sockets, stream, deadlock

I am using java sockets for communication. On the client side I have some processing and at this point I send an object to the cient. The code is as follows:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 3000);
    OutputStream os = server.getOutputStream();
    InputStream is = server.getInputStream();

    CommMessage commMessage = new CommMessageImpl();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    oos.writeObject(commMessage);
    os.write(bos.toByteArray());
    os.flush();

    byte[] buff = new byte[512];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    ByteArrayOutputStream receivedObject = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buff)) > -1) {
      receivedObject.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
      System.out.println(receivedObject);
    }
    os.close();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
  } catch (IOException e) {
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  }
}
```

Next on the server side I have the following code to read the object and write the response (Which is just an echo message)

```
public void startServer() {
  Socket client = null;
  try {
    server = new ServerSocket(3000);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Waiting for connections.");
    client = server.accept();
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Accepted a connection from: " + client.getInetAddress());
    os = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    is = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

    // Read contents of the stream and store it into a byte array.
    byte[] buff = new byte[512];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    ByteArrayOutputStream receivedObject = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buff)) > -1) {
      receivedObject.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    // Check if received stream is CommMessage or not contents.
    CommMessage commMessage = getCommMessage(receivedObject);
    if (commMessage != null) {
      commMessage.setSessionState(this.sessionManager.getState().getState());
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
      oos.writeObject(commMessage);
      os.write(bos.toByteArray());
      System.out.println(commMessage.getCommMessageType());
    } else {
      processData(receivedObject, this.sessionManager);
    }
    os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
      try {
        is.close();
        os.close();
        client.close();
        server.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

The above code works ok if I do not try to read data on the client side (If i exclude the code related to reading). But if I have that code, for some reason, I get some kind of deadlock when accessing input streams. Any ideas what I might have done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both client and server are attempting to read the whole input stream (i.e. everything up to EOF) but neither is sending an EOF (by calling `shutdownOutput()` on the socket.)

Why do you need to store the object data temporarily in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`? This would probably be easier to fix if you read directly from the socket input stream.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the solution later today... But the reason why I use ByteArrayOutputStream is because I don't know what will come from the client - the stream can contain one of two types of objects. So what I do is that I fully read the stream and try to convert to one object - if that fails it can only be the other object (or an error :)). Do you think I should do it some other way?

Comment: Just read it into an Object and use instanceof. I can't see how what you're doing adds anything to that, you still have to do that anyway.

Comment: You're right. I should do some refactoring obviously. Thanks for pointing that out.