# Socket input stream hangs on final read. Best way to handle this?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm a bit stumped on how to avoid my socket hanging on read.  Here's my code:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("someMachine", 16003);
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    try {
        outputStream.write(messageBuffer.toByteArray());
        outputStream.flush();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        int result;
        while ((result = in.read()) != -1) {
            response.append(Character.toChars(result));
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");  //never gets printed
     } catch (...) {}
```

The above code successfully reads all the data from the stream but then hangs.  Reading up on the net I was expecting to receive a -1 from the server (which I can't control) to indicate that I had reached the end of stream but instead I get this:

```
(Lots of data above this point)
57
10
37
37
69
79
70
10
```

It then hangs.  So, my questions are:

1) Have I coded this wrong or is there an issue with the server's response?

2) If there is an issue with the server's response (i.e. no -1 being returned), how can I work around this (i.e. to stop reading when it hangs).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: is "someMachine" closing the socket after sending the last byte? is it waiting for some reply/acknowledge to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java deadlock problem....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797087/java-deadlock-problem)

Comment: fixed in my case when I added, at the end of the server side, `socket.close()` or `socket.shutdownOutput()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with just stopping where read would hang is that this can happen in 2 cases:

1: server doesn't have any more data to send

2: The server has sent more data, but your client has not received it yet due to network overload.

And you only want to really stop reading in the first case, but you want read to block in the second case.

The way to solve this is to make a transfer protocol(Standard) which allows the server to tell the client how much data it expects to send.

If the server knows the total data size in advance, simply start by sending the total number of bytes in the transfer, and then send the data. That way the client knows when it have received all data.

(Or the server can simply close the connection when done. That way `read` should fail, but this only work if you don't need the connection in the future)

Comment: Yes, I think you've got to the heart of this.  I do have a content-length header I can take advantage of which I think will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I think you will only get -1 when the server decides to stop the conversation, i.e. closes its output stream or closes the socket completely. Else, the stream stays open for potential future incoming data.

Comment: Ah, good point, hadn't thought of that.  However, this still leaves me scratching my head as to how I know my own input stream has completed.

Comment: It's a matter of protocol definition. What kind of data is exchanged? Is it structured? Does it have an end character or sequence? Does it have a fixed length?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Android expert, but this seems to work just fine on Android:

```
    try {
        telnetClient = new Socket(server, port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (telnetClient.isConnected()) {
        try {
            InputStream instr = telnetClient.getInputStream();
            int buffSize = telnetClient.getReceiveBufferSize();
            if (buffSize > 0) {
                byte[] buff = new byte[buffSize];
                int ret_read = instr.read(buff);
                screen.append(new String(buff, 0, ret_read));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            screen.append("Exception while reading socket:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this exact same problem. I solved it by setting a timeout straight after creating the socket object...
    socket.setSoTimeout(10 * 1000);

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem to be pretty formidable. I was trying to execute a windows batch command from java and the process hangs every time trying to read the inputstream from the command getting executed.

I could only fix this inelegantly.

a) By looking for a specific line which I know would signal the end
       useful information form the stream.
b) Or to start a new Thread that
       kills the process at the other end of the socket, in this case for
       me IEDriverServer.exe after a wait time.

```
String[] cmdArray = {"cmd.exe","/c",cmd+ " 2>&1" };
    InputStream is = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray).directory(f).start().getInputStream();

        error_buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        int lines=0;

        while((line=error_buffer.readLine())!=null){
            if(line.startsWith("[INFO] Final Memory: ")) {
                break;
            }

            log.debug("Reading cmd Stream "+line);
            buf.append(line);
            lines++;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
while ((result = in.read()) != null) {
```

Comment: This does not compile as in.read() returns an `int` which cannot be compared to `null`.  I think instead you meant to say `while ((result = in.readLine()) != null) {`, but this does not work either.

Comment: Also, read is a blocking call. This is going to hang the lock up the tread. If you're using any multihreading this is going to lock up a processor